# cmake Get all definitions for target including definitions coming from global scope, directory scope and dependacy targets

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(untitled3)

add_executable(untitled3 main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(untitled3 PUBLIC X=xxx -DY=yyy)
add_definitions(-DA=aaa -DB=bbb)

#get_property(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS DIRECTORY PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
get_target_property(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS untitled3 COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
message(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")
```

CMake output:

```
-- COMPILE_DEFINITIONS X=xxx;Y=yyy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/kyb/devel/untitled3/cmake-build-debug
```

`make VERBOSE=1` shows:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.cpp.o
g++-9  -DA=aaa -DB=bbb -DX=xxx -DY=yyy  -g -o CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.cpp.o -c /.../main.cpp
```

I would like to see all definitions allied to that target. How?

Comment: Try also INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS

Comment: Your output misses `-DA=aaa` and `-DB=bbb` compile definitions which are defined as *directory property*. You have line which reads that property.. but this line is commented out. Why do you comment that line?

Comment: get_property or get_target_property. one gives A and B, second X and Y. How get both? And how to get this two pairs and also definitions from parent scope? It is a question.

Comment: INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS gives the same result as COMPILE_DEFINITIONS

Comment: "how to get this two pairs" - Just read both ones and combine them. "also definitions from parent scope" - The property of the parent directory is already incorporated into the current directory, no needs to bother about the parent.

Comment: what about definitions from targets on which this one depends?

Comment: "what about definitions from targets on which this one depends?" - Yes, this is the most difficult problem. You may try to read `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` **target**'s property at the very end of your `CMakeLists.txt`, probably CMake would incorporate dependent targets into the property at that moment. But it could be that even at the end of the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` the properties of the dependent targets are still not incorporated. In that case you may try to read property with `file(GENERATE)` approach: it would save into the file the property at the end of the whole configuration stage.

Comment: You need to check all properties and variables individually that contribute to the target.  Don't forget that individual files can have their own properties.  You're probably better off just trying to use the file api or generate the json file that gives you the info you want.